# Adding 3 values to the plist Dynamically and then overwriting one one by one if added more

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I m using `plist` in my application,i am able to add the values in the `plist` and its working fine.but what i need is only 3 values should be added to the `plist` and thereafter if tried to add more values it should overwrite the previous three values ..one by on eon subsequent additions..

**Here is my code which adds many x values:**

```
-(void) myplist :(id) sender
{

 NSLog(@"mylist  Clicked");    
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// get paths from root direcory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    // get the path to our Data/plist file
NSLog(docsDir);

NSString *plistPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

//This copies objects of plist to array if there is one
[array addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]];
[array addObject:searchLabel.text];
// This writes the array to a plist file. If this file does not already exist, it creates a new one.

[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep a variable that stores the index at which the last item was inserted (`lastInsertionIndex below)`. Assuming the plist currently has 3 items & the 4th one is being inserted (lastInsertionIndex = 2), the code should look something like-

```
// get paths from root direcory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];    // get the path to our Data/plist file
NSLog(docsDir);

    NSString *plistPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    //This copies objects of plist to array if there is one
    [array addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]];

//If plist has less than 3 items, insert the new item. Don't use lastInsertionIndex. Else, replace one of the items.
if([array count] < 3)
{
     [array addObject:[searchLabel.text]];
}
else
{
//Update lastInsertionIndex
lastInsertionIndex++;
lastInsertionIndex %= 3; // Max size of array = 3

[array replaceObjectAtIndex:lastInsertionIndex withObject:[searchLabel.text]];
}

[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: hi akshay thanks for your reply...can u tell me how is the lastInsertionIndex declared..

Comment: If you need to write to your plist across lifetimes of your application, you will need to save lastInsertionIndex as well. You can save it using NSUserDefaults. Please mark it as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: ok,,actually when i used your code,compiler gave an error saying that "undeclared identifier lastinsertionindex."..so what to do for this..

Comment: Obviously it will. It was just a sample. In the code above I have assumed that the plist already has 3 items, and hence lastInsertionIndex is 2. You can add NSUInteger lastInsertionIndex = 2;.

Comment: whether i sholud applu here a if condition to check wheteher the lastinsertion index ==2..and then increment it,correct me if i m wrong

Comment: Coming back to 0 from 2 is already handled by lastInsertionIndex %= 3.

Comment: Hi akshay,what if my plist is empty?,i have written the below code..          `code`NSUInteger   lastInsertionIndex=0;
    lastInsertionIndex++;
   lastInsertionIndex %= 3; // Max size of array = 3
   
  // [array replaceObjectAtIndex:lastInsertionIndex withObject:[searchLabel.text]];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:lastInsertionIndex withObject:searchLabel.text];
    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];

Comment: Hi Akshay please tell me how to store the index..because here u have assumed that lastinsertionindex =2..but what id the plist is empty how to check it..

Comment: updated the code to check when the plist has less than 3 items.

Comment: Hi akshay..I am not getting can u provide me with a code snippet